# Python - how to parse strings from an array?

Tags: python, arrays, string, parsing

I'm a Java/C programming, struggling to learn Python.  (I'm writing in Python 2.4.3 on a Linux machine.)  I have a simple program which telnets to a Cisco router, logs in, then captures the config.  The router's config is stored in a variable named "output":

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import telnetlib
import datetime
import sys

def telnetFunction( host ):
  print("Telnetting to device "+host+"...\n")
  tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
  # ...use tn.read_until() and tn.write() to log into the router...  ...this works...
  tn.write("terminal length 0"+"\n")
  tn.write("show run"+"\n")
  tn.write("exit"+"\n")
  output=tn.read_all()      # router config stored as "output"
  return output

host = "192.168.102.133"
output=telnetFunction( host )
```

The above code works.  From using a bunch of different print() statements, I can see that the router's config is all in "output", which I am assuming is an array of newline-terminated strings....?  Not entirely sure about that; the telnetlib documentation doesn't specify.

My problem now is I need my program to step through output again, extracting one string at a time.  I need something like:

```
while(iterating through output)
   tmpString = output.getNextStr()
```

So if output looked like this:

```
Current configuration : 34211 bytes\n!\nversion 12.3\nno service pad\n...etc...
```

I need tmpString to equal the follow in each iteration of the loop above:

```
tmpString = "Current configuration : 34211 bytes"
tmpString = "!"
tmpString = "version 12.3"
tmpString = "no service pad"
```

I've been Googling for a few hours, but am stumped.  (Part of the problem is I'm not clear that "output" is indeed an array.  Could it be a string?)  I've played with split() and using []'s but no luck so far.  Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?  Thanks, -ROA

Comment: You are working with *lists* not arrays, firstly. In any event, `output` looks like it's a string.

Comment: You're just splitting on the `\n`s?

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.4.3? It's over 11 years old.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Interesting.  Lists, not arrays?  I never would have guessed that.  Do you know this from experience, or is there some documentation out there that I haven't uncovered?  The hardest thing about learning python is that sometimes you just don't know what data type you are working with.  Thanks...!

Comment: @aryamccarthy  Correct.  The '\n' characters are part of the original chunk of data I read in

Comment: @Blender.  Good question.  We are a network shop that does little coding, so most of our coding tools are really old.  I've been petitioning to upgrade our Python for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated in your example, let say output is defined as

```
output = 'Current configuration : 34211 bytes\n!\nversion 12.3\nno service pad'
```

Your next step is to split the string by \n so

```
output_list = output.split('\n')
```

this will generate the following list

```
output_list = ['Current configuration : 34211 bytes', '!', 'version 12.3', 'no service pad']
```

then you can iterate over this list.

to tie it all together

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import telnetlib
import datetime
import sys

def telnetFunction( host ):
  print("Telnetting to device "+host+"...\n")
  tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
  # ...use tn.read_until() and tn.write() to log into the router...  ...this works...
  tn.write("terminal length 0"+"\n")
  tn.write("show run"+"\n")
  tn.write("exit"+"\n")
  output=tn.read_all()      # router config stored as "output"
  return output

host = "192.168.102.133"
output=telnetFunction( host )
output_list = output.split('\n')
for item in output_list:
    print item
```

Comment: Perfect!  Your code solved the problem, thanks.  I wasn't aware you could convert a large string into a list with split() - that's def a trick for my notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable tn is, I'm assuming, treated like a file handle. So when you read this 'file' once, the pointer is at the end of the file and needs to be reset:

```
tn.seek(0)
```

Call this before you execute your second loop.

Alternatively, you can iterate over output like so:

```
for line in output.split("\n"):
    print line
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't think tn is a file handle.  It seems to be an array or a string or something saved in local memory.  However, your use of split() looks promising, thanks!